# Swift CoreBluetooth Not a valid characteristic for peripheral exception

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am getting this error message when I write to a BLE peripheral.

> WARNING: "is not a valid characteristic for peripheral"

[CoreBluetooth] WARNING: <CBCharacteristic: 0x107ba2030, UUID = AC02, properties = 0x1E, value = <7b226574 223a224e 50227d>, notifying = NO> is not a valid characteristic for peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x109217ad0, identifier = D9CD0AE5-E3AB-2190-D333-0FA16950CEFE, name = MKP-246f28a6df58, state = connected>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to provide a little more information for people to give a meaningful answer. However to speculate a little...

It is saying the Characteristic with the UUID `AC02` is not a valid characteristic. Looking at the list of officially adopted characteristics, it is not in the list.
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics/

So my assumption is that it is a custom characteristic which is difficult to know anything about from the information in your question.

You might want use a generic tool that allows you to explore your Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device. On mobile devices, the Nordic nRF Connect app is available on [android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp) and [ios](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/nrf-connect/id1054362403).

On many desktop platforms you can use the Chrome browser by going to the URL `chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices`.

These generic tools should allow you to explore and interact with the peripheral. The additional information it gives might help debug the issue you are having with the app you are writing.

Comment: I have solved this problem, at first when ble didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service with characteristics i store all character discovered to a list [CBCharacteristic] then write to exactly characteristic of peripheral